# Why Vim file path autocompletion (CTRL-X CTRL-F) stops as soon as the path contains square brackets?

Tags: vim, autocomplete, path, brackets

I don't know how to do autocomplete with CTRL-X CTRL-F for a path containing square brackets. E.g. /home/matt/Mail/Imap/imap.googlemail.com/[Gmail].sbd/ .
The autocompletion stops after the directory [Gmail].sbd. It seems that the square brackets are blocking further path completion. How can I prevent this behavior ? Is it a bug or a configuration problem ? I don't find the answer in vim documentation. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Please type `:set isfname?` to check whether it contains `[,]`.
If not, you should type `:set isfname+=[,]` to add them.

Comment: I had isfname=@,48-57,/,.,-,_,+,,,#,$,%,~,=. Now I have isfname=@,48-57,/,.,-,_,+,,,#,$,%,~,=,[,] but it still does not work.